# Record audio from mic and save as .wav django web app

Tags: django, flash, audio

I have created a web application using django , html  and jquery( and js ).
I need to record audio from a mic and store it as a .wav file. What is the best way to go about doing this ? (Better if it's supported on most browsers like chrome, firefox, safari)
I don't mind using a flash plugin if it's easy to understand and use.
Please suggest good ideas and links.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Flash highly compresses the audio data before sending it, if you use the conventional ways of acquiring data from microphone. That is, if you use [NetStream.publish()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#publish%28%29) with a microphone attached to it. I'm actually not sure about the format, but would imagine that it is something proprietary... could be MP3. But it could be also Speex... at least I know that Flash supports this format.

Now, [Microphone class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html) is capable of exposing the raw sound data within the application. You need to listen to `sampleData` event dispatched from its instance. However, the documentation, for some reason, doesn't cover that... This is *relatively* new feature, so, perhaps they just forgot to add it in the docs. [Here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d1d.html) however, they posted an example of how to do that (scroll to the "Capturing microphone sound data" paragraph). You will need to write the "encoder" for WAV data yourself, but the format it outputs the audio is already some sort of PCM, so you will only need to write the proper headers (or so I think).